# Vertical alignment of Pictures in Div

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see from the above picture, how can I vertically align them to the middle of the grey box, where they have equal height of top and bottom.

Code:

```
<div style="height: 290px; width: 210px; background-color: grey;">
    <img src="${ImagePopulator}${MainProductImage}"style="padding: 20px 0;"/>
    <img src="${ImagePopulator}${MainProductImage}"style="padding: 20px 0;"/>
</div>
```

I tried with the above style, but it seems to only adjust the top of the picture. I can't get it to align to the middle. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Easiest way is probably with flexbox: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22218694/703717

Comment: @Danield So funny! :))

Answer (score 1):

Since the images are inline elements by default, use the methods that apply to vertically center text with CSS will work for this case.

For example, use `line-height` will work like this:

```
<div style="height: 290px; width: 210px; background-color: grey; line-height:250px;">
    <img src="${ImagePopulator}${MainProductImage}"style="padding: 20px 0;"/>
    <img src="${ImagePopulator}${MainProductImage}"style="padding: 20px 0;"/>
</div>
```

Use flex box will also works fine. If you are willing to set the img to a block element, then you can use some other tricks like `transform` or negative `margin`.

For example:

```
<div style="height: 290px; width: 210px; background-color: grey; position: relative;">
    <img src="${ImagePopulator}${MainProductImage}"style="display: block; margin-top:-145px;top 50%; position:relative; height: 100%; padding: 20px 0;"/>
    <img src="${ImagePopulator}${MainProductImage}"style="display: block; margin-top:-145px;top 50%; position:relative; height:100%; padding: 20px 0;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these css to the element you want to align in the center.

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

[Look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqy4j6rp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this css -

```
display: flex; or, -webkit-flex
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column; or, row
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following styling, added to your code:

```
<div style="height: 290px; width: 210px; background-color: grey; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTKfww8iUXidrKRO9vnHq3rWTJdcXK8YCIhSPTMxrQ9yD1EdlnX" style="padding: 20px 0;"/>
</div>
```

[Here is a working example with the above code](http://plnkr.co/edit/e5ZOZhO5AYEc3sEmf7UJ?p=preview).

Which produce the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this**

```css
.block{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 120px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
img{
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="block">
  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ModernPGP/icons/master/keys/icon-fingerprint.png">
 </div>
```

> When you use `display: table-cell` then you are able to use `vertical-align` CSS property